# MS Access copy/paste of table fails with message about clipboard size

Tags: ms-access-2010

I have an mdb file that has some large tables in it (greater than 65000 rows). I used to not have any problems duplicated the table by copying and pasting but just recently I started getting a message about the size of the clipboard not being able to hold more than 65000 lines.  What's weird is the operation works on another computer with the same version of Access (32bit 2010) and the same table and doesn't report this error message. It just started reporting this message on the "problematic" computer recently, and nothing has changes as far as I know except for Windows automatic updates. Any help appreciated.

Comment: Maybe your computer has less free memory than the other one.

Answer (score 0):

What's wrong its trying to copy such amount of data (straight from a table, mind you) to the Clipboard. But since this is Access we're talking it wouldn't shock me that's suggested over Exporting the data safely into a format like .CSV or Even better .SQL
Is funny that you mentioned the system architecture because on first sight I would check that as possible cause.

I would highly suggest changing the approach into something more around this lines: https://support.office.com/en-us/article/Introduction-to-importing-and-exporting-data-08422593-42dd-4e73-bdf1-4c21fc3aa1b0